# Variable not available in script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm using passportjs to do user authentication on my express app. But I've ran into a strange problem:

On my index route I'm rendering the index.jade template with the user parameter

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});
```

Now in my jade template I have the following

```
block content
  if user
    h1 logged in #{user}
    script var shared_resources.user = user
  if !user
    h1 Not logged in
```

For some reason, the conditional pass fine in that user is there. And also when I print out the user object in logged in #{user} it prints out the details fine. However inside the script tag, I'm getting an uncaught reference, user is not defined. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use template string in scrip tag as well.

```
script var shared_resources.user = "#{user}"
```

If you want to embed object you can try following.

```
script var shared_resources.user = !{JSON.stringify(user).replace(/<\//g, '<\\/')}
```

Comment: Okay that works but I was having additional problems when user is an object. It looks like jade doesn't parse the json properly so the object gets a syntax error. I decided to just pass in the username string and everything works fine.